# Android - Get soft keyboard to automatically pop up when a dialog is displayed?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad

I currently pop up a custom dialog with an EditText in it.
Currently the keyboard will only pop up when the user clicks "into" the EditText.

Is it possible to get the keyboard to pop up for the EditText as soon as the Dialog loads?

I have tried:

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextd);
editText.setFocusable(true);
editText.requestFocus();
```

But it hasn't worked.

Has anyone any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you are requesting focus on the appropiate text edit, its easy to make a mistake there, when you obtain the editText make sure you are calling findViewById like this:

dialog.findViewById(editTextId);

And then do what you are doing.

Comment: Yes, I've checked I am calling the correct one and I do use findViewByid before requesting focus.

Comment: I suppose you don't like to do that if the user happens to have a real keyboard?

Comment: I will, its a VoIP app that doesn't orientate so I would like the keypad to pop up automatically when the dialog starts anyway

Comment: Show us the context that the code you posted is in